# Creating object in django model form with foreign key

Tags: django-forms, foreign-keys

I am inserting a new record in my model form where my model is child form containing a foriegn key. When I am submitting the form it give error it should be instance of the foriegn key.

Here is my model

```
class MMEditidState(models.Model):
  state_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
  state_dremelid = models.ForeignKey(MMDremelDump, db_column = 'state_dremelid')
  assignee = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
  state = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
  role = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
  date = models.DateTimeField() 
  class Meta:
    db_table = u'mm_editid_state'
  def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s' % (self.state_dremelid, self.assignee)

  class MMEditidErrors(models.Model):
     error_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
     error_stateid = models.ForeignKey(MMEditidState, db_column = 'error_stateid')
     feature_type = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
     error_type = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
     error_nature = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
     error_details = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
     error_subtype = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
     date = models.DateTimeField()
  class Meta:
     db_table = u'mm_editid_errors'
  def __str__(self):
     return "%s" % (self.error_dremelid)
  def __unicode__(self):
     return u'%s' % (self.error_dremelid)
```

Here is my View

```
def qcthisedit(request, get_id):
  if request.method == "POST":
     form = forms.MMEditidErrorForm(get_id, request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
     return http.HttpResponseRedirect('/mmqc/dremel_list/')
  else:
    form = forms.MMEditidErrorForm(get_id)
    return shortcuts.render_to_response('qcthisedit.html',locals(),
                                  context_instance = context.RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my form

```
class MMEditidErrorForm(forms.ModelForm):
   def __init__(self,get_id, *args, **kwargs):
     super(MMEditidErrorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     dremel = MMEditidState.objects.filter(pk=get_id).values('state_id')
     dremelid = int(dremel[0]['state_id'])
     self.fields['error_stateid'] = forms.IntegerField(initial = dremelid, 
                                                   widget = forms.TextInput(
                                                              attrs{'readonly':'readonly'}))
     feature_type  = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices = formfields.FeatureType)
     error_type  = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices = formfields.ErrorType)
     error_nature = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices = formfields.ErrorNature)
     error_details = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices = formfields.ErrorDetails)
     error_subtype = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices = formfields.ErrorSubType)
     class Meta:
        model = models.MMEditidErrors
        exclude = ('error_id','date')
```

When I submit the form I am getting the error

```
Cannot assign "1": "MMEditidErrors.error_stateid" must be a "MMEditidState" instance.
```

So I have added line

```
get_id = MMEditidState.objects.get(pk = get_id)
```

Now I am getting the below mentioned error

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'MMEditidState'
```

in `form = forms.MMEditidErrorForm(get_id, request.POST)`

Can someone help on this

Thanks
Vikram

Comment: I have used custom forms instead of model forms it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by simply using the custom forms instead of model forms. While storing the data in the database, I managed myself in the views.py